# Implementing properties declared in interfaces in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to `Kotlin`, so I have this interface.

```
interface User {
    var nickName : String
}
```

Now I want to create a class `PrivateUser` that implements this interface. I have also to implement the abstract member `nickName`.

Via constructor it's very simple

```
class PrivateUser(override var nickName: String) : User
```

However when I try to implement member inside the class `Idea` generates me this code

```
class Button: User {

override var nickName: String
    get() = TODO("not implemented")
    set(value) {}
}
```

It's confusing to me how to implement it further.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to achieve? You can just use `override var nickName: String = "hello"` is you don't want to implement a getter and a setter. And if you want, then just add an implementation for these getters and setters.

Comment: the problem is I don't know how to add implementation. For example the ``value`` in set method, where should I store it ? in the ``nickName`` variable ? I tried it but get kind of ``recursive`` call

Comment: Then just use the simple form I gave you in my previous comment. getters and setters are useful if you want to store the value elsewhere. Or if you want side-effects.

Comment: @SchiduLuca You can use `field` to store it in the backing field of the property. Like `set(value) { field = value }`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Properties must be initialized in Kotlin. When you declare the property in the constructor, it gets initialized with whatever you pass in. If you declare it in the body, you need to define it yourself, either with a default value, or parsed from other properties.

Some examples:

```
class Button : User {
    override var nickname = "Fred"
}

class Button(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) : User {
    override var nickname = "${firstname[0]}$lastname"
}
```

The code generated by IDEA is useful if you want a non-default getter and/or setter, or if you want a property without a backing field (it's getter and setter calculate on the fly when accessed).

More examples:

```
class Button : User {
    override var nickname = "Fred"
        get() = if (field.isEmpty()) "N/A" else field
        set(value) {
            // No Tommy
            field = if (value == "Tommy") "" else value
        }
}

class Button(val number: Int) : User {
    var id = "$number"
        private set
    override var nickname: String
        get() {
            val parts = id.split('-')
            return if (parts.size > 1) parts[0] else ""
        }
        set(value) {
            field = if (value.isEmpty()) "$number" else "$value-$number"
        }
}
```