# Implementing a property that uses a class

Tags: kotlin

In the following code:

```
class MyValidator: MySubject {        
    override val subject = NonNullableBehaviourSubject(ValidationResponse())
}


class NonNullableBehaviourSubject<T : Any>(defaultValue: T) : Subject<T>() {
{

interface MySubject {
   var subject: ...
}
```

MyValidator implements the interface MySubject. This interface has a property called subject. How do I define this property for the class NonNullableBehaviourSubject?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing properties declared in interfaces in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882797/implementing-properties-declared-in-interfaces-in-kotlin)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html

Comment: You don't need to specify `T: Any` because every class already extends `Any`.

Comment: @sonnet You do, because nullable types _don't_ extend `Any`. `T : Any` constraint means "only non-nullable `T` allowed".

Comment: @AndroidDev Why `...` for the type of `subject`?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface A<T: Any> {
    val c: C<T>
}

class B<T: Any> : A<T> {
    override val c: C<T> = C<T>()
}

class C<T: Any> {

}
```

Pretty self-explanatory. Declare your field as a `val` in the interface if you need the implementation to be `val`s or declare it as `var` and your implementations should use `var` as well.

Edit: Since it's generics, you have to pass in the types as well.

Comment: It might be "self explanatory" but the compiler complains about NonNullableBehaviourSubject: "One type argument expected for class NonNullableBehaviourSubject<T: Any>"